# Swift - UISwitch to change background colour - only works once?

Tags: ios, swift

Learning Swift from scratch. Why does my UISwitch code only work once when trying to change the UIVIew background colour? I've seen something about IBOutlet, but don't know how to add. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  testChangeBackground
//
//  Created by Paul Balfour on 14/08/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var mySwitch = UISwitch()

@IBAction func mySwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
println("Switched")
    changeBackground()

}

func changeBackground() {
    if mySwitch.on {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

---

Aha. So the UISwitch also needs to be an outlet to work. - What I don't understand is why an IBOutlet too? (working below). Thanks

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func mySwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
println("Switched")
    changeBackground()

}

@IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!


func changeBackground() {
    if mySwitch.on {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're creating a

```
var mySwitch = UISwitch()
```

once, but this is not hooked up to anything, so when you check whether or not that switch is on, it doesn't work. What you need to do is hook up this variable to a IBOutlet, like you mentioned in your post. That way, when your UISwitch is actually toggled, the variable will correctly represent the state of the switch. To do this, do something similar to how you created your IBOutlet for your Action. It should look something like this:

```
    @IBOutlet var mySwitch: UISwitch!
```

You should be able to create this by control dragging from a storyboard/xib like you did for your action.

Comment: Great. Can you explain why the UISwitch needs to also be IBOutlet too when its not being affected?. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it's not being affected? You are toggling the state of the switch on the display, and therefore you need some way to listen to that. The IBOutlet let's you pick up what's happened to your switch, while the IBAction performs an action when it is toggled. Another way you could have done it, now that I look at it again, is by passing the switch you get as "sender" to the changeBackground method, since the sender is the correct UISwitch.

Comment: Ahh I see. I was only thinking in terms of just performing the IBAction when the switch was toggled. Didn't realise I also need to listen for the toggle. Thanks for clarifying.